# Second loop pagination changes URL, not content

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

I'm reasonably new to WordPress and I believe I am missing something conceptual here.

I have assigned a static post to be my front page. My front-page.php template begins with a standard loop:

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>            
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <h2><?php the_title()?></h2>
            <?php the_content(__('Continue Reading'))?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>    
<?php else : ?>
    <h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
    <p class="center"><?php _e("Empty Text Here."); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This successfully outputs the content of my post.  Great.

Now I am attempting to insert a second loop below this that will output a finite list of other posts followed by a pager.  The pager shows up and when it is clicked the page reloads as expected, but the content remains unchanged. Here is my second loop?

```
<?php
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args=array(
    'paged'             =>  $paged,
    'posts_per_page'    =>  2, 
    'post_type'         => 'type_here'
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);?>
<?php if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) :?>
    <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post(); ?>  
        <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
    <?php endwhile;?>
    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo 'Empty Text Here';?>
<?php endif;?>
```

My taxonomy pages all paginate perfectly so I'm thinking my mistake is programmatically subtle or conceptually flagrant. Is it not possible for a post template to feature a secondary loop with its own pagination?

Given that pagers generate a loop agnostic URL I am guessing that WP assumes that only the original loop qualifies for paging?

> http://mysite.com/page/2/

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According with the Wodrdpress Codex: [Pagination on static front page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page#Pagination) uses the `page` query variable, not the `paged` variable. See the [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for details.

Comment: I see it now. "Static front pages are not intended to be paged." I wonder how one is supposed to provide a pagable front with a page title and intro text that can be modified without touching PHP files? I guess that is for another day. Thanks.